# return this в Обобщенном классе

Tags: c#

```
class GenericClass<T> : SomeBaseClass where T : SomeBaseClass
{
    public T GetT()
    {
        return this as T;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: этот код работает, но я не понимаю как. Если Т будет неким SomeDerrivedClass, который наследуется от SomeBaseClass, тогда каким образом происходит преобразование this (т.е. экземпляра GenericClass<Т>) к типу T?

UPD: ступил, метод GetT() возвращает null, да.
Вопрос возник во время прочтения этой статьи на хабре:
[ссылка на статью](https://habr.com/post/426789/)
Там приведен такой код:

```
public class MonoBehaviourSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T Instance;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        Instance = GetInstance();
    }

    protected T GetInstance()
    {
        return this as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну компилироваться, положим будет, и даже не упадет в runtime, просто вернет `null`, так как данное преобразование невозможно.

Comment: Этот код действительно работает или возвращает null, т.к. не смог преобразовать тип?

Comment: Это попытка приведения типа, вы попытаться привести можете к чему угодно (ну почти к чему угодно)

Comment: как выглядит `DerrivedClass`?

Comment: @Grundy class DerrivedClass : BaseClass { }

Comment: _MonoBehaviourSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour_ - собственно тут класс явно наследуется от типа который может быть передан в качестве generic параметра.

Comment: я вот тоже не понял пассаж про "не наследуется от"

Comment: @Grundy но в качестве generic параметра может быть передан класс, который тоже наследуется от MonoBehaviour. В таком случае this всегда будет возвращать null?

Comment: @teran то я в собственных правках запутался. Пофиксил вопрос.

Comment: в примере в статье или опечатка или глупость - так работать не будет. Вероятнее всего вместо `return this as T;` должно быть `return Instance as T;` или даже `return Instance;`, раз уж автор пишет про универсальный синглтон.

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо.